# Java Programming Simple If/Else statement project

Tags: java, if-statement

Ok guys so I'm stuck trying to write some code in java, I cant get the code to display the pricing option for fullsize. **I can't get the program to continue onto the second option I have listed as Case 2.**

The project basically gives the user the option to **ask if he is renting a car [Y or N]**:

- if Y is inputed the next question

  - it ask is **"Compact of Full-size?"**,

    - if the user selects compact the project displays that the user has selected compact and
    - if the code displays fullsize the project displays that the user has selected fullsize.
- Then it asks the user if they have a coupon if the users answer Y for the coupon the price is 7% off of 30.50.

  - If the user answers N the price is a normal 30.50. The fullsize normal price is 40.50 and the price with a coupon is 7% off of 40.50. The following is the code i have written currently.

The code:

```
public class CarRental {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            System.out.println("Programmed by .");

            double standardCompact = 30.50;
            double couponCompact = ((30.50) - (30.50 * 0.07));
            double standardFullSize = 40.50;
            double couponFullSize = ((40.50) - (40.50 * 0.07));

            //Scanner Input
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Rent a Car? [Y or N]: ");

            //Response String
            String response = input.next().toUpperCase();

            if (response.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println("You entered no. Bye. ");
            } else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.print("Compact or Full-Size? [C or F]: ");

                //case1
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("C")) {
                    System.out.println("You selected Compact. ");
                } else if (response.equals("F")) {
                    System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");

                    System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                    response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                    if (response.equals("N")) {
                        System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardCompact + " " + "per     day.");
                    } else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                        System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponCompact + " " + "per day.");
                        //case 2
                        response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                        if (response.equals("F")) {
                            System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size.");
                            System.out.println("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                            if (response.equals("N")) {
                                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardFullSize + " " + "per day.");
                            } else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponFullSize + " " + "per day.");

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This works as intended for me, can you explain the issue in more detail?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the Full-size option? When I select the Full-size option it stops the loop without displaying a price.

Comment: Yes, I got `Have coupon? [Y or N]:`. But I'm not sure if I matched the missing brackets. I would strongly recommend you to use an IDE with auto-formatting.

Comment: It is nowhere written that all code must go in main. For example, if you have established that he rents a car with standard price p, then you can factor out the coupon handling into a method that asks for the coupon and based on that returns the correct price.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, I'm a bit new to the programming world but this definitely helped.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some `}`s after your `else` clauses. Example:

```
        response = input.next().toUpperCase();
        if (response.equals("C")) {
            System.out.println("You selected Compact. ");
            //Put code that should only execute if you select Compact here.
        }else if(response.equals("F")){
            System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");
            //Put code that should only execute if you select Full-size here.
        //Should have a } here!
        //Put code that should always execute here.
```

Because you never close the block of code in the `else` clause, all of the code that follows is still part of the `else`, and therefore will only be executed if the `else` is selected, not under every circumstance as you had intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening lots of brackets `{` but not closing them where you need `}`.

I usually not just handing the code, but I've noticed you done must of the job, but confused where to close the brackets and a little bit at the program flow.

I only changed it a bit, there is a lot that you can cut and reuse code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.println("Programmed by .");

        double standardCompact = 30.50;
        double couponCompact = ((30.50)-(30.50 * 0.07));
        double standardFullSize = 40.50;
        double couponFullSize = ((40.50)-(40.50 * 0.07));


        //Scanner Input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Rent a Car? [Y or N]: ");

        //Response String
        String response = input.next().toUpperCase();

        if (response.equals("N")){
            System.out.println("You entered no. Bye. ");
        }
        else if (response.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.print("Compact or Full-Size? [C or F]: ");



            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("C")) {
                System.out.println("You selected Compact. ");

                //case1
                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardCompact + " " + "per     day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponCompact + " " + "per day.");
                }

            }
            else if(response.equals("F")) {
                System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");

                //case 2

                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardFullSize + " " +    "per day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponFullSize + " " + "per day.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I've been trying to create another If else statement to print out.. "You must enter either C or F" or either Y or N for each set of statements and I cant get it to work either way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is all your code is under the if statemente for Full-Size so the case 2 only executes when you select full-size , Yes to coupon and after showing the final message you press F again the code should look like this.

```
  public class CarRental {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

    System.out.println("Programmed by .");

    double standardCompact = 30.50;
    double couponCompact = ((30.50)-(30.50 * 0.07));
    double standardFullSize = 40.50;
    double couponFullSize = ((40.50)-(40.50 * 0.07));


 //Scanner Input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Rent a Car? [Y or N]: ");

//Response String
    String response = input.next().toUpperCase();

    if (response.equals("N")){
        System.out.println("You entered no. Bye. ");
    }else if (response.equals("Y")) {
        System.out.print("Compact or Full-Size? [C or F]: ");

//case1

        response = input.next().toUpperCase();
        if (response.equals("C")) {
            System.out.println("You selected Compact. ");
            System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardCompact + " " + "per     day.");
            } else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponCompact + " " + "per day.");
           }
        //case 2
        }else if(response.equals("F")){
            System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");
            System.out.println("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardFullSize + " " +    "per day.");
            } else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponFullSize + " " + "per day.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see in the code above is really important to correctly close conditional blocks so the code really does what you expect it to do.

Using flow diagrams is a good support for learning how programming languages really work.